# How to simulate click on canvas with webgl by coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, click, webgl

I want to simulate clicks on https://www.thesnidewalk.com/ For example simulate clicks on "walk" button at start menu.

I tried this, got coordinates on button and made mouse event and dispatched it:

```
const newEv = new MouseEvent("click", {
  clientX: 1274,
  clientY: 970
});

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.dispatchEvent(newEv);
```

At console I got "true" but it not affected on this canvas game. I have tried to put at mousEevent  coordinates from screen offset and coordinates exactly of canvas, but nothing help.